# how to calculate Distance between two coordinates using Mapbox Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mapbox

how can I get the Distance out of Mapbox Navigation Route? in Double Format, I don't want to draw the route I just need to calculate the distance between two Points, I have been able to calculate the distance using Truf

```
Storelocation = Point.fromLngLat(Stores.latitude, Stores.longitude)
Userlocation = Point.fromLngLat(UserLocation.Latitude, UserLocation.Longitude)
Distance = TurfMeasurement.distance(Storelocation, Userlocation, TurfConstants.UNIT_KILOMETERS)
```

but the problem is with this method above it doesn't calculate distance within the route, it is just calculate straight line from point to point ***for example*** in Google map the distance is 9 Km, but with this method above the distance is 6 Km

```
private fun getRout(){
        NavigationRoute.builder(this)
            .accessToken(Mapbox.getAccessToken()!!)
            .origin(Userlocation)
            .destination(Storelocation).build().getRoute(object :Callback<DirectionsResponse> {
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<DirectionsResponse>, response: Response<DirectionsResponse>) {
                    val rout = response ?: return
                    val body = rout.body() ?: return
                    if (body.routes().count() == 0 ){
                        return
                    }
                    navigationMapRoute = NavigationMapRoute(null, mapView, map)
                    // Get Distance
                    Distance = ??

                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<DirectionsResponse>, t: Throwable) {

                }
            })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
navigationMapRoute = NavigationMapRoute(null, mapView, map)
                // Get Distance
                Distance = ??
```

Do this:

```
val route = response.body().routes().get(0)
val distance = route.distance()
```

Comment: because of this answer is correct i will accept it as an answer, i just figure this out along time ago but thanks any way better than unanswered question